# Entity Framework Core jsonb column type

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using Entity Framework Core with npgsql postgresql for Entity Framework Core.

My question is, using migrations, how do I mark a class property to generate a JSONB column type?

For example:

```
public class MyTableClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // My JSONB column
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Byte[] and in the entity mapping set column type to jsonb ?

Comment: Were you able to query jsonb using ef core? e.g. to query properties of json doc

Comment: zaitsman, think that is not possible at this moment. Look at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4021 . I have a sql query for that. I am using this to read the result: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862#issuecomment-331081468 . I already found an issue with this code, related with DateTimeOffset and DateTime. If you hit this issue, i can show you my workaround.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Based on H. Herzl comment:

My final solution was something like this:

```
public class MyTableClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Migrations generated this:

```
Data = table.Column<string>(type: "jsonb", nullable: true),
```

When updated the database with migrations, the Data column was created correctly with jsonb type.

Comment: @Alex Klaus this link is unfortunately dead.

Comment: @wegry, here is the link - https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/general.html#explicitly-specifying-data-types

Comment: When I tried to do this, I added a migration (add-migration), then I did update-database and I got the error "42804: column "my_olumn" cannot be cast automatically to type json" - so I dropped the table and let EF code first re-create them ("update-database"), but again no luck. The column my_olumn existed before as a string. Can you help? What is wrong? By the way, after "jsonb" was failing, I also tried "json" - same error.

Comment: @Matt, that is strange. How is possible that the column already exists if you dropped the table?

Comment: @bruno.almeida - that is due to the "migration history" - EF.Core Code First keeps every step and I had that column "my_column" as text there in previous migration steps. So what I found out is that EF Core is trying to convert "text" into "jsonb" - which fails. Even in pgAdmin it is not possible to select jsonb if you edit the table and want to change the column datatype. The only thing that worked is if you create a new column of type "jsonb" with a different name and then delete the old column. If the column didn't exist before, then you're lucky. Maybe throwing away some migr. steps helps.

Comment: @Matt, do these steps:  1- delete the column (from class); 2 - create a new migration; 3 - add the column again to the class; 4 - create a new migration.

Comment: @bruno.almeida - Good idea! I tried it as you suggested, and it worked like a charm. Many thanks for helping me out! You saved my day! **One note:** You can also use JsonDocument from System.Text.Json as datatype, if you don't have a POCO class and the JSON you're storing is based on different schema. (More details [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco))

Comment: some additional details at: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.htm

Answer (score 25):

using `string` as was suggested by @bruno.almeida is a nice solution but **couldn't be queried**.

additional approaches are to use:

- As System.Text.Json DOM types (`JsonDocument` or JsonElement)
- As strongly-typed user-defined types (POCOs)

`JsonDocument` being my favorite since it could be queried, is flexible and fast to setup, e.g.:

```
public JsonDocument Customer { get; set; }
```

more details at: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html

Comment: Nice write-up @ link regarding the available options.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the response by @bruno.almeida, it is worth noting that it is possible to add a type to the JSONB column. For example, I have recently been creating a column to hold various file upload errors:

I have a `RecordErrors` class that I think is generic enough to be used in many of my error storage situations:

```cs
public class RecordErrors
{
    public IEnumerable<ResultError> Errors { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<ResultError>();
}
```

The `ResultError` class just has additional properties such as `ErrorCode` and `Message` but could just as easily be replaced with `String` if you wanted simple string error values.

My Entity then looks like this:

```cs
public class MyFileUpload
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(800)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    ...

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public RecordErrors? Errors { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Running migrations created the column with the `jsonb` type.

You can then save data to the database in the usual way using:

```cs
 _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The result in the database in my instance is JOSN that looks something like:

```json
{
  "Errors": [
    {
      "Code": "Columns.Unsupported",
      "Message": "The upload contains the following unsupported column headings: Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4."
    }
  ]
}
```