# How to convert a class instance to JsonDocument?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, npgsql

Let's say we have an entity class that looks like this:

```
public class SerializedEntity
{
    public JsonDocument Payload { get; set; }

    public SerializedEntity(JsonDocument payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }
}
```

According to [npsql](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#jsondocument-dom-mapping) this generates a table with column `payload` of type `jsonb` for this class which is correct.

Now what I would like to do is take *any* class instance and store it as `payload` in this table e.g.:

```
public class Pizza {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

should then be possible to be retrieved as an object with following structure:

```
{Name: "name", Size: 10}
```

So I need something like this:

```
var pizza = new Pizza("Margharita", 10);
var se = new SerializedEntity(someConverter.method(pizza))
```

Comment: What framework and version are you on? There's Newtonsoft [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/4.7.1). But availability may depend on framework/version.

Comment: Entity Framework core 3.1.2

Comment: Then maybe have a look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Comment: ^^ Which is only about serializing into string ... give me a minute ...

Comment: Turns out, from object to JsonDocument is not as straight forward as I first thought. Upvoting Question.

Comment: It's suprising to me too since JsonDocument is what you must define to get a correct mapping to `jsonb`.

Comment: You _could_ work around that by using [string mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco#string-mapping) but I guess you'll prefer JsonDocument...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#how-to-write-net-objects-to-json-serialize) it's a little awkward but possible:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var pizza = new Pizza("Margharita", 10);
var se = new SerializedEntity(JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(pizza)));
```

It has been built-in to dotnet core since (I think) v3.0, so you do not need any additional 3rd party libs. Just don't forget the `using`s.

There may be some tricks to get the parsing a little more efficient, though (using async API, perhaps or as Magnus suggests by serializing to binary using `SerializeToUtf8Bytes`).

**I haven't been able to find any approach that goes directly from `T` or `object` to `JsonDocument`.** And I cannot believe this is *not* possible somehow. Please leave a comment if you know how that works or add your answer.

Comment: The output of JsonSerializer.Serialize is a string, whereas my constructor takes JsonDocument. I can convert an object to string and then use JsonDocument.Parse to create a JsonDocument, but since I want to save it later to the db I guess it will be serialized again.

Comment: Edited to reflect your need to use JsonDocument @pbn

Comment: Note that JsonDocument is Disposable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: >> I haven't been able to find any approach that goes directly from T or object to JsonDocument

System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument

Answer (score 14):

You can use [JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetodocument?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializeToDocument__1___0_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) which was added in .NET 6. In your case you would end up with this:

```cs
var pizza = new Pizza("Margharita", 10);
var se = new SerializedEntity(JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument(pizza))
```

Comment: +1 brilliant! Here's a link to [JsonSerializer.Write.Document.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Document.cs) for anyone interested in how the underlying implementation works, especially the [WriteDocument()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Document.cs#L112) method which seems to use the "serialize then parse" approach shown by other answers (though more efficiently).

Comment: To go the other way round (from `JsonDocument` to an object) there's no `DeserializeFromDocument()` method, but there are several overloads of the `Deserialize()` method like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize(system-text-json-jsondocument-system-type-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) that do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Serailize it and than parse it to JsonDocument.

```
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(
                new Pizza {Name = "Calzone", Size = 10}));
```

Comment: So, there's _really no way_ around serialize/parse?

Comment: @Fildor Is seem the were [thinking about it](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/34099) but abandoned the idea for now.

Answer (score 3):

If your EF entity (`SerializedEntity`) will always have a Pizza as its serialized JSON document, then you can simply use [POCO mapping](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#poco-mapping) - replace the JsonDocument property with a Pizza property, and map it to a jsonb column.

If the actual types you want vary (sometimes Pizza, sometimes something else), you can also map an `object` property to jsonb, and assign whatever you want to it. Npgsql will internally serialize any object to JSON:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using var ctx = new BlogContext();
        ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

        ctx.FoodEntities.Add(new FoodEntity { SomeJsonFood = new Pizza { Name = "Napoletana" } });
        ctx.FoodEntities.Add(new FoodEntity { SomeJsonFood = new Sushi { FishType = "Salmon" } });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FoodEntity> FoodEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("...");
}

public class FoodEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public object SomeJsonFood { get; set; }
}

public class Pizza
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class Sushi
{
    public string FishType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do this with entity builder? I don't want attributes in entity classes

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67014297/241296

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for me:

```
public class SerializedEntity
{
    public object? Payload { get; set; }

    public SerializedEntity(object? payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }
}
```

and the EF configuration for it:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SerializedEntity> builder)
{
    builder.Property(n => n.Payload).HasColumnType("jsonb").HasConversion(
        v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v,
            new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}),
        v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object?>(v,
            new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}));
}
```